# unable to export hbase table onto local file system

Tags: hbase

I'm newby with hbase. What I want to do is just `EXPORT` table onto local file system and `IMPORT` into table of remote machine.

I tried to run export with mapreduce driver on the HMaster like below...

```
$ jps
21910 HMaster
17858 NameNode
3885 JobHistoryServer
20197 QuorumPeerMain
18327 ResourceManager
3949 Jps
24908 hbase-region-inspector-0.3.4
26973 Bootstrap
620 RunJar

$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver export my_table /hadoop
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2016-07-19 14:09:48,019 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-07-19 14:09:48,101 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Export: versions=1, starttime=0, endtime=9223372036854775807, keepDeletedCells=false
2016-07-19 14:09:48,158 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,159 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.mapoutput.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.value.class
2016-07-19 14:09:48,160 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
2016-07-19 14:09:48,160 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
2016-07-19 14:09:48,160 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
2016-07-19 14:09:48,161 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.mapoutput.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.key.class
2016-07-19 14:09:48,162 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: dfs.df.interval is deprecated. Instead, use fs.df.interval
2016-07-19 14:09:48,162 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.http.address
2016-07-19 14:09:48,162 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.userlog.retain.hours is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.userlog.retain.hours
2016-07-19 14:09:48,162 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
2016-07-19 14:09:48,162 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.local.dir.minspacestart is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.local.dir.minspacestart
2016-07-19 14:09:48,162 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.shuffle.read.timeout is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.read.timeout
2016-07-19 14:09:48,162 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: io.sort.spill.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.sort.spill.percent
2016-07-19 14:09:48,162 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.parallel.copies is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.submit.replication is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.submit.file.replication
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.local.dir.minspacekill is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.local.dir.minspacekill
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.profile is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.profile
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.heartbeats.in.second is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.heartbeats.in.second
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.compress is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.healthChecker.interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.healthchecker.interval
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.timeout is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.timeout
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.temp.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.cluster.temp.dir
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: jobclient.completion.poll.interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.completion.pollinterval
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker.persist.jobstatus.active is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.active
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.compression.codec is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.shuffle.merge.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.max.attempts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.maxattempts
2016-07-19 14:09:48,163 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.reduce.input.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.input.buffer.percent
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.cache.levels is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.taskcache.levels
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: io.sort.factor is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jobtracker.instrumentation is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.instrumentation
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.userlog.limit.kb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.userlog.limit.kb
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.speculative.execution.slowNodeThreshold is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.speculative.slownodethreshold
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.reduce.memory.mb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.map.max.skip.records is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.skip.maxrecords
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker.jobhistory.lru.cache.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.jobhistory.lru.cache.size
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker.persist.jobstatus.hours is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.hours
2016-07-19 14:09:48,164 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker.handler.count is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.handler.count
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: io.sort.mb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.profile.maps is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.profile.maps
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.min.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.child.java.opts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.java.opts
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tasktracker.dns.nameserver is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.dns.nameserver
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tasktracker.taskmemorymanager.monitoring-interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.taskmemorymanager.monitoringinterval
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tasktracker.expiry.interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.expire.trackers.interval
2016-07-19 14:09:48,165 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.max.tracker.failures is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maxtaskfailures.per.tracker
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.jobtracker.split.metainfo.maxsize is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker.persist.jobstatus.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.dir
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: job.end.retry.attempts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.end-notification.retry.attempts
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.job.counters.limit is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.counters.max
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.tracker.task-controller is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.taskcontroller
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jobtracker.maxtasks.per.job is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.maxtasks.perjob
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.child.log.level is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.log.level
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.max.attempts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.maxattempts
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.output.compression.codec is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec
2016-07-19 14:09:48,166 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent
2016-07-19 14:09:48,167 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.tracker.report.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.report.address
2016-07-19 14:09:48,167 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: keep.failed.task.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.files.preserve.failedtasks
2016-07-19 14:09:48,167 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.used.genericoptionsparser is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.genericoptionsparser.used
2016-07-19 14:09:48,167 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: tasktracker.http.threads is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.http.threads
2016-07-19 14:09:48,167 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.speculative.execution.slowTaskThreshold is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.speculative.slowtaskthreshold
2016-07-19 14:09:48,167 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.acls.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.cluster.acls.enabled
2016-07-19 14:09:48,167 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.child.java.opts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.java.opts
2016-07-19 14:09:48,167 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.max.tracker.blacklists is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.tasktracker.maxblacklists
2016-07-19 14:09:48,167 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tasktracker.indexcache.mb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.indexcache.mb
2016-07-19 14:09:48,167 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.attempts.to.start.skipping is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.skip.start.attempts
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: jobclient.output.filter is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.output.filter
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jobtracker.restart.recover is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.restart.recover
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.local.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.cluster.local.dir
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.speculative.execution.speculativeCap is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.speculative.speculativecap
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: jobclient.progress.monitor.poll.interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.progressmonitor.pollinterval
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.child.log.level is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.log.level
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.compression.type is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker.retiredjobs.cache.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.retiredjobs.cache.size
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tasktracker.dns.interface is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.dns.interface
2016-07-19 14:09:48,168 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.profile.reduces is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.profile.reduces
2016-07-19 14:09:48,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: job.end.retry.interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.end-notification.retry.interval
2016-07-19 14:09:48,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jobtracker.job.history.block.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.jobhistory.block.size
2016-07-19 14:09:48,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.child.tmp is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.tmp.dir
2016-07-19 14:09:48,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
2016-07-19 14:09:48,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.committer.job.setup.cleanup.needed is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.committer.setup.cleanup.needed
2016-07-19 14:09:48,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum
2016-07-19 14:09:48,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.queue.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.queuename
2016-07-19 14:09:48,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jobtracker.taskScheduler is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.taskscheduler
2016-07-19 14:09:48,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.reduce.max.skip.groups is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.skip.maxgroups
2016-07-19 14:09:48,169 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.healthChecker.script.timeout is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.healthchecker.script.timeout
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tasktracker.instrumentation is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.instrumentation
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.system.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.system.dir
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.inmem.merge.threshold is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.merge.inmem.threshold
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.map.memory.mb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.memory.mb
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: topology.script.number.args is deprecated. Instead, use net.topology.script.number.args
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: dfs.umaskmode is deprecated. Instead, use fs.permissions.umask-mode
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: topology.node.switch.mapping.impl is deprecated. Instead, use net.topology.node.switch.mapping.impl
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tasktracker.tasks.sleeptime-before-sigkill is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.tasks.sleeptimebeforesigkill
2016-07-19 14:09:48,170 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
2016-07-19 14:09:48,171 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.merge.recordsBeforeProgress is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.merge.progress.records
2016-07-19 14:09:48,171 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: mapred.shuffle.connect.timeout is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.connect.timeout
2016-07-19 14:09:48,708 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-common-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,710 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,711 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-client-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,712 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CompatibilityFactory, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,713 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-server-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,714 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,715 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,715 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class com.google.protobuf.Message, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,716 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class com.google.common.collect.Lists, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,717 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.cloudera.htrace.Trace, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/htrace-core-2.04.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,717 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.cliffc.high_scale_lib.Counter, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,723 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-common-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,723 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-client-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,724 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-server-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,725 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,725 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,726 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,727 DEBUG [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: For class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.HashPartitioner, using jar /hadoop/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar
2016-07-19 14:09:48,841 INFO  [main] client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at iot-prod-ndb1/220.90.216.91:8032
2016-07-19 14:09:48,982 ERROR [main] security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://mycluster/hadoop already exists
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver.main(Driver.java:54)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://mycluster/hadoop already exists
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export.main(Export.java:189)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
        ... 5 more
```

`hbase-site.xml` configured like below...

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://mycluster/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>ndb1:2181,ndb2:2181,ndb3:2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.ipc.server.tcpnodelay</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.ipc.client.tcpnodelay</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.handler.count</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Any advice would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this solution may help.
`hdfs://mycluster/hadoop`
Delete the output directory before running this job
execute `hadoop fs -rm -r/hadoop`  before running job.